# Add as quantity drop down in cart page of debut theme shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shopify

Hi I am working on the Shopify Debut theme. I want to add quantity selector as a drop-down in cart page.

But iam not able to do so. I have added the drop down on my product page with the help of this code

```js
          <input id="quantity" type="number" name="quantity" value="1" class="tc item-quantity" />
<select name="quantity" id="quantity">
         {% for i in (1..4) %}
                  <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
          {% endfor %}         
</select>
```

This is working fine, but i am not able to do so on my cart template. Here is the code for my cart template as well

```js
<div class="cart__qty">
                  <label for="updates_large_{{ item.key }}" class="cart__qty-label" data-quantity-label-desktop>{{ 'cart.label.quantity' | t }}</label>
                  <input id="updates_large_{{ item.key }}" class="cart__qty-input" type="number"
                    name="updates[]" value="{{ item.quantity }}" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*"
                    data-quantity-input data-quantity-item="{{ forloop.index }}" data-quantity-input-desktop>

                </div>
```

Please guide how can i make this work for cart page as well

Answer (score 1):

This should work with Debut theme, what you need to do is change `<input>` to `<select>`.

```
<div class="cart__qty">
    <label for="updates_large_{{ item.key }}" class="cart__qty-label" data-quantity-label-desktop>{{ 'cart.label.quantity' | t }}</label>
    <select id="updates_{{ item.key }}" class="cart__qty-input" value="{{ item.quantity }}" data-quantity-input data-quantity-item="{{ forloop.index }}" data-quantity-input-desktop>
      {% for i in (1..4) %}
        <option value="{{ i }}" {% if forloop.index==item.quantity %}selected{% endif %}>{{ i }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

EDIT:
Also keep in mind that in Debut theme inside cart-template.liquid there are two places where you need to update your code. One is for mobile version and one for desktop.

Here's the code for mobile as well:

```
            <div class="cart__qty medium-up--hide">
              <label for="updates_{{ item.key }}" class="cart__qty-label" aria-label="{{ 'cart.label.quantity' | t }}" data-quantity-label-mobile>
                {{ 'cart.label.qty' | t }}
              </label>
              <select id="updates_{{ item.key }}" class="cart__qty-input" data-quantity-input data-quantity-item="{{ forloop.index }}" data-quantity-input-mobile>
                {% for i in (1..4) %}
                    <option value="{{ i }}" {% if forloop.index==item.quantity %}selected{% endif %}>{{ i }}</option>
                {% endfor %}   
              </select>
            </div>
```

Comment: let me try, Thankyou

Comment: Thankyou so much. for your help

Comment: insted of dropdown i am using now plus and minus icon. it is working fine on. product page

Comment: <div class="qtybox">
          <span class="btnqty qtyminus icon icon-minus">-</span>
          <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" class="quantity-selector quantity-input" readonly="">
          <span class="btnqty qtyplus icon icon-plus">+</span>
        </div>

Comment: can you help me for the cart as well

Comment: My code above is for the cart page. Where is the code you just posted from?

Comment: This is the code i have taken from this link, but it is only for product page

Comment: https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Plus-Minus-Quantity-Selector-on-Supply-Theme-Using-Cart-Page/td-p/426540

Comment: Are you sure you've edited the code in correct place, there are 2 spots in cart-template.liquid where you need to change it, see my edit of the original answer above.